# Do not use empty rulesetscss(emptyRules)

Tags: html, css

Please help me i have made a class in html and using in css buy selector . (dot) but VScode is showing error

```
.header-area{
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code CSS error "Do not use empty rulesets"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32464170/visual-studio-code-css-error-do-not-use-empty-rulesets)

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Visual Studio Code (VSCode) from showing warnings for empty rules in CSS files, follow these steps:

Open your Visual Studio Code (VSCode).

Press Ctrl + Shift + P (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + Shift + P (Mac) to open the command palette.

Type "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" and select it from the list of options. This will open the settings.json file.

Search (using Ctrl+F) for :

```
"css.lint.emptyRules": "warning",
```

And change it to the following:

```
"css.lint.emptyRules": "ignore",
```

This configuration tells VSCode to ignore empty rules in CSS files.

Save the settings.json file.

After saving the changes, Visual Studio Code should no longer display warnings for empty rules in CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

VScode provides you with a helpful CSS linter, this is basically telling you that you should have something inside your class. e.g.

`.header-area{}` - will throw a warning,

`.header-area{background-color:red;}` - will not throw a warning